# Using \verbatiminput{} on files containing $

Tags: verbatim, external-files

I'm fairly new to LaTEX and I'm trying to include a file in the appendix using the following instructions:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \footnotesize{\verbatiminput{pattern-representations}}
\end{multicols}
```

However, the file `pattern-representations.tex` contains a lot of lines with `$` character thus resulting in the following error:

```
ERROR: Missing $ inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                $
l.291 ...e{\verbatiminput{pattern-representations}
                                                  }^^M
--- HELP ---
TeX probably found a command that can be used only in math mode when
it wasn't in math mode.  Remember that unless stated otherwise, all
all the commands of Section 3.3 in LaTeX Book (Lamport) can be used
only in math mode. TeX is not in math mode when it begins processing
the argument of a box-making command, even if that command is inside a
math environment. This error also occurs if TeX encounters a blank
line when it is in math mode.
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:
The minimum example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim, multicol}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2260}{\neq}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{301}{\'}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\section{Appendix}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \footnotesize{\verbatiminput{pattern-representations}}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

`pattern-represetnations` contents are [here](https://pastebin.com/wjpR2gKQ)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you using the `fancyvrb` package? Does the problem go away if you don't use a `multicols` environment? Please advise.

Comment: note that `\footnotesize` does not take an argument so the syntax should be `footnotesize\verbatiminput{pattern-representations}` but please make a complete example that shows the error so it can be debugged.

Comment: A small test doesn't show the issue.

Comment: @Mico I don't use `fancyvrb` package. The problem doesn't go away if I don't use `multicols`.

Comment: Please, make a minimal example; the appearance of `^^M` in the error message is suspicious.

Comment: @egreg, that may be because I'm using Emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you define the Unicode `≠` character to be `\neq`, which requires math mode. Fix its definition.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-test.tex}
65 .$(.;)$(.).                  
66 @()@≠()                      
67 @--@...                      
68 @--@..$.$                    
69 @-@..-.                      
70 @-@...                       
71 @-@....                      
72 @-@..$,.$                    
73 @-@..$-.$                    
74 @-@..$.$                     
75 @́@...                        
76 ≠                            
77 ≠,                           
78 ≠,,                          
79 ≠,,,
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim, multicol}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2260}{\relax\ifmmode\neq\else\textneq\fi}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{\'}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\textneq}{%
  \begingroup
  \ooalign{\hidewidth/\hidewidth\cr=\cr}\vphantom{/}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\section{Appendix}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \footnotesize{\verbatiminput{\jobname-test.tex}}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Note however that the acute accent is placed on the *following* character: there's no way to use postfix combining characters in `pdflatex`.

[image]